# ERROR 1728 (HY000): Cannot load from mysql.user. The table is probably corrupted

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

**symptom:** I just tried to create a user, as I have done many times in the past, only to receive this error:

> ERROR 1728 (HY000): Cannot load from mysql.user. The table is probably
>   corrupted

**cause:**
The only things I've done that I can think of since I last created a user through phpMyAdmin that may have caused this would be apt-get upgrades.  As far as I can tell all user accounts work fine (testing all would be a long process) and other databases are able to read/write/etc fine

**troubleshooting:**

**upgrade:**
I've already tried `mysql_upgrade` which both reports that table (and all others) as OK, and required the `--force` option. I've done a full `apt-get upgrade dist` and rebooted (followed by another `mysql_upgrade` - hey why not) and the issue persists.

**permissions:**
I've verified the permissions in all files south of `/var/lib/mysql` are mysql:root rw:rw:--  (which were originally mysql group too but only visible by user) including `/var/lib/mysql-files` (empty) `/var/lib/mysql-keyring` (one file) and `/var/lib/mysql-upgrade` (one file)

**users:**
I have two root users (different name, nearly identical privileges) and both show up with full access to mysql.user (which shows and is able to quickedit fine - though the full edit is missing the BLOB files, could this be the problem?) through phpMyAdmin.

**create user methods:**
I get the same error when using `CREATE USER 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';` as when trying through phpMyAdmin - through both my root accounts

At this point I'm stack-overflow shy of re-installing MySQL or perhaps even Ubuntu, and the closest articles I see are for mysql.proc (which haven't worked)

**update logs show:**

> [Warning] Incorrect definition of table mysql.user: expected column
>   'password_expired' at position 41, found 'password_last_changed'.
>
> [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Cannot load from mysql.user. The table is
>   probably corrupted

Answer (score 4):

Even after re-running `mysql_upgrade`, the columns of user are still in the wrong order.

My (inelegant) solution was to:

1. Export users
2. Rearrange the table column definitions (swap `password_expired` with `password_last_changed`)
3. Import as `user2` (just to be sure)
4. `DROP TABLE user;` (oh my!)
5. Copy `user2` to user (thankfully it worked!)